# Vue3 doesn't detect bearer token right before it gets stored

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, vuejs3, vuex

I have this code where I call my API for a login and in response I get the token.

With that, I can then call my API using the Bearer token and get the current logged in user data.

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post('user/login', {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password
  })
  .then( async (response) => {
    console.log(response.data)

    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

    const userdata = await axios.get('user/userdata');

    this.$store.dispatch('user', userdata.data.userDataDTO);

    this.$router.push('/home');
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
  })           
} catch(err){
  console.log('login failed')
  this.failedToLogin = true;
}
```

The problem is that, for some reason, I keep getting 401 when the code gets to the userdata call, even though I've already added my token in the previous step. It doesn't matter how many times I execute this, it keeps throwing the Token and next, the 401 error.

I also programmed my app to detect if I already have the token stored when the page gets refreshed, so it automatically logs the user in. Since the token is already registered, I can just refresh the Login page and it will instantly get logged in. This makes no sense for me, can someone help?

Comment: Is `axios.get` set up to automatically use the token from local storage?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, in a separate file like this: "axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');". I just did like Prerak Sola commented below, in the same line, to make sure the token is there... a bit weird that it doesn't work with the separate file though

Comment: That code is likely only executing the one time, when the axios instance is first created. You probably want a request interceptor, which will execute for each request: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `axios` is not configured to fetch the token from local storage, you will need to pass it as a header in your `GET user/userdata` request.

One of the ways to do that is to update your GET request to:

```js
const userdata = await axios.get('user/userdata', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }
});
```

You can refer the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) for more details about the request config object.

Comment: Thanks! So, I had axios configured like that in a separate file like this: "axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');"  so I thought it was good enough, but looks like the API call happened before this other file got the Token... I just executed this as you did and works perfectly, at least like this it makes sure th token is there already

Comment: " I thought it was good enough" - you can always debug, just add a new line with `debugger` (before or above for example) and the browser will stop at that line, you can easily evaluate the object and see if at that time you do indeed have the values you expect 

Comment: Along with what @balexandresuggested suggested, you can also add a **request interceptor** to debug the request before it is sent.